# Accumulate query params with NULL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have this screen with many textboxes which are the criteria section.

**Example :**

Enter Name: <kbd>***_*__*_*_**</kbd>

Enter Age: <kbd>***_*__*_*_**</kbd>

Enter Height: <kbd>***_*__*_*_**</kbd>

<kbd>Search !</kbd>

And so ,  the query is something like this :

```
select * from....
where 
...
and Name = isnull(@name,Name)
and Age= isnull(@Age,Age)
and Height= isnull(@Height,Height)
```

All fine.

Now let's say all 3 params are `null`

The problem is  (for example ) in a situation where **column** `Name`  contains `null`. ( no values on db column)

And so --it yields something like this

`and Name = isnull(@name,Name)`
 which translates to
`and Null = isnull(Null,Name)`
 which translates to
`and Null = Null`  (because the column [Name] value is "null")

And this is where is goes bang. (because null !=null)

I don't want to use the `set ansi null` solution.

Is there any other elegant solution for this ?

## edit :

Hmm... I could use this

`ISNULL(Name ,1)  = ISNULL(@Name ,ISNULL(Name ,1))`

But I'm not sure if it's the best solution...

Comment: if both `@name` and `Name` are `NULL`, would you like to select the record?

Comment: try this `and (Name = @name OR (NAME IS NULL AND @name IS NULL))` (*not tested*)

Comment: `ISNULL(Name ,1) = ISNULL(@Name ,ISNULL(Name ,1))` -- will kill index if you have one.

Comment: re: `ISNULL(Name ,1) = ISNULL(@Name ,ISNULL(Name ,1))`, it's unusual to mix data types, i.e. a string and an integer, that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a test in the format

```
@var IS NULL or @var = Column
```

There are several other reasons why this is a better format but I can't remember them off the top of my head.  But your query will end up looking like this.

```
select * from....
where 
...
and (@name IS NULL OR @name = Name )
and (@age IS NULL OR @age = Age)
and (@height IS NULL OR @height = Height)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your SQL query to something like this :

```
select * from....
where 
...
and (Name = @name OR (@name IS NULL AND Name IS NULL))
and (Age = @Age OR (@Age IS NULL AND Age IS NULL))
and (Height = @Height OR (@Height IS NULL AND Height IS NULL))
```

Comment: Just made an edit, I missed the point you want to match only the exact NULL value